# Rails DateTime.now without Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I need to use DateTime.now to grab the current date, and "strip off" the time.

For example, this shows what I *don't* want: `DateTime.now =>  Sat, 19 Nov 2011 18:54:13 UTC +00:00`

This shows what I *do* want: `DateTime.now.some_operation => 2011-11-06 00:00:00 UTC`

Comment: DateTime without Time is Date :) do you mean Date.today?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You can use one of the following:

- `DateTime.current.midnight`
- `DateTime.current.beginning_of_day`
- `DateTime.current.to_date`

Comment: @sekmo beginning_of_day is part of the activesupport (rails).

Comment: Better to not use `DateTime.now` without zone. It's better to use one of `Time.zone.now`, `DateTime.current`, `DateTime.now.in_time_zone`, `DateTime.now.utc`, `DateTime.now.getlocal`, `DateTime.now.iso8601`, `DateTime.now.jisx0301`, `DateTime.now.rfc3339`, `DateTime.now.to_i`, `DateTime.now.to_f` instead.

Comment: thanks @BryanDimas, your comment helps. Does VPN can affect, if chaning ip to other countries?

Answer (score 27):

What you need is the function strftime:

```
Time.now.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

Comment: This can cause significant problems if you are inserting data into a database that expects `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` formatted data as it will invert the month and day value

Comment: My proposal was to use the function strftime, the used format you have to customize yourself accordingly

Answer (score 11):

You can use just:

```
Date.current
```

Answer (score 9):

What about `Date.today.to_time`?

Comment: This reminds me I needed a fast one so I benchmarked few approaches and Date.today was the fastest.

Answer (score 5):

If you're happy to `require 'active_support/core_ext'`, then you can use

```
DateTime.now.midnight # => Sat, 19 Nov 2011 00:00:00 -0800
```

Comment: Just noticed the ruby-on-rails tag, so I guess you _are_ happy to require ActiveSupport :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want today's date without the time, just use `Date.today`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. This works:

```
DateTime.now.in_time_zone.midnight
```